# http get in nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, https, http-get

```
var http = require('http');
exports.get = function(){
  var options = {
    host: 'http://stackoverflow.com/'
  };

  http.get(options, function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
  }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
  });
};
```

gives me error as `Got error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://stackoverflow.com/ http://stackoverflow.com/:80`
I use the documentation; https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.2/api/http.html#request.url

What can be the problem, I added port number to the option as;

```
var options = {
  host: 'http://stackoverflow.com/'
  port:443 //also  port:8080,  port:80, port: 8118
};
```

but still there is no solution. Is it about corporate proxy?

How can I reach the link?

Comment: Look at using the request module: https://github.com/request/request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Host is not URL. Try

`stackoverflow.com` for host.

```
var options = {
     host: 'stackoverflow.com',
     port: 80,
     path: '/',
     method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
   console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
   console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
   ...
```

Comment: I wrote as your example but it still gives me `uncaughtException: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

This problem sometimes occur depending on hosts, some hosts like 'stackoverflow.com' might return 200 and in some cases like 'google.com' will probably return 301 status code, so you should fill host variable like below to get status code 200:

```
var options = {
    host: 'www.google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
};
```

with host: 'www.google.com' I get 200 for status code.
but with host: 'stackoverflow.com' only when I remove 'www.' I will get status code 200.

anyone having this problem, you should try both with and without 'www.' to get the proper result.